# Empty fields get submitted on form even though I have required validation in them?

Tags: html, forms

I have required validation on three of my fields in my form.

When I submit with nothing in them, they get submitted to the database which crashes my program even though I have required in them.

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal" tabindex="-1">Add</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data- 
dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add Work Order/Service Request</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="popup">
  <form action="{{ url_for('background_process') }}" method="POST">

           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

            <input type="url" id="url" name="url" required />

            <input type ="text" id="mdp-demo" name= "mdp-demo" required />

                <a href=# id=process_input><button 
 class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
        </form>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>



</head>

<body>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="popup">
  <form action="{{ url_for('background_process') }}" method="POST">

           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

            <input type="url" id="url" name="url" required />

            <input type ="text" id="mdp-demo" name= "mdp-demo" required />

                <a href=# id=process_input><button 
 class='btn btn-default' >Submit</button></a>
        </form>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i have used the same code but it gives me